# Circled Latin Capital Letter M on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, unicode, nsstring

I have tried just getting Ⓜ on iOS but there seems to be bugs with It everywhere. Converting a string with text like "MMMMmMMM" to the circled letters will result in "Ⓜ️Ⓜ️Ⓜ️ⓜⓂⓂⓂ". I have tried the unicode version of the letter but everywhere I put it will work the same. If i copy and paste Ⓜ It will also be converted into the Emoji. So I cannot just insert Ⓜ at the beginning of a text field/view, and cannot get Ⓜ as a UIButton title. Does anybody know of a solution or workaround to get the correct version of this character for UIButton title and inserting anywhere in a body of text?

Edit: Here is the code

```
[button setTitle:@"Ⓜ" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setTitle:@"\u24C2" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Either of these ways with a system UIButton result in the same thing, the emoji Metro M.

Edit 2: Changing the font of the button to another will make the button display the correct version, but since the text is inserted into a UITextField or UITextView or anything else, the text is inserted as that font which turns It into emoji.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: I don't understand what an "emoji metro M" is and how it differs from Ⓜ.  Can you explain please?

Comment: This is the emoji metro M -> Ⓜ️

Comment: OK, so it looks like the code you posted is working?!?  What did you expect to appear on the button title?

Comment: The non-emoji version, Ⓜ.. I have all the other letters, and the lowercase circled latin letter m works fine. Just the capital will convert to an emoji which looks off with everything else.

Comment: It looks like Apple used that code point for an emoji in their system font.  You can see it listed [here](http://www.grumdrig.com/emoji-list/) under the code point 24C2 (Safari-only).

Comment: @Maximilian: I think that the answer to the "duplicate question" should apply here as well (i.e. append the "Unicode variation selector"). Let me know if that does not help, then I will re-open then question.